# Why Firefox doesn't resize correctly the "select" tag with custom "letter-spacing"?

Tags: firefox, select, input, width, letter-spacing

I added some 'letter-spacing' to my 'select' and I noticed that Firefox doesn't change the width of the rendered 'select', meanwhile chromium does.

The result is that the user can't see the entire content of select.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>select input width with letter-spacing</title>
        <style>
        select {
            appearance: none;
            border: none;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option>hello world</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try it with Firefox or Chromium and see the different.

I tried to fix with 'width: max-content' or similar but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be happening - I've filed a bug report with Mozilla so hopefully it gets fixed.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1851397